invoiceplane docker has php error connection reset by peer
i try to launch invoiceplane project
this code is from github
project source: https://github.com/InvoicePlane/InvoicePlane
all container except php is work correctly
but have an error when :
curl iv.test.local:9000/index.php 
--------------------------------------------------
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer;
--------------------------------------------------

at the here
i edit docker-compose as following:

"""
services:
  # --- PHP 8.1
  php:
    container_name: "invoiceplane-php"
    build:
      context: ./resources/docker/php-fpm
      args:
        - PUID=1000
        - PGID=1000
        - TZ=UTC
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/projects/invoiceplane:delegated
      - ./resources/docker/php-fpm/php-dev.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
"""


when i try to curl iv.test.local/index.php/setup 
reply "curl: (52) Empty reply from server"

when try to curl iv.test.local:9000/index.php/setup
reply "curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer;"

